# Efficient use of sockets in c#

Tags: c#, sockets

I am using Sockets in C#.

I am using this to connect:

```
client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
client.Connect(remoteEP);
```

I send a message using `client.send`...

I receive a message using `client.receive`...

I have read to maximise the performance of using sockets I should use Ayscn Sockets.

Is this true and is there an optimised buffer number to use?  e.g buffer[256] (etc).

Also, on the Server side I assign a thread to an incoming client request.  Once the work is completed i close the socket. I have found this a good way to manage clients but I have also found suggestions that this is not the best way to go.  Really just  need advice on the best way to go and why.

thanks..

Comment: "Ayscn Sockets"? You probably meant async ?

Comment: thank you for the spelling correction..

Comment: I know this question has been asked many times but i get conflicting advice so it would be nice to see if there is a definitive answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async IO is for when you have many sockets (far more than the number of CPUs). In other cases it does not change the performance profile (except that it goes a tiny bit slower because it has more overhead).

Async is about initiating and completing an IO. The actual work that the IO has to perform does not change. Using async cannot magically make the network faster.

Comment: Hi, thank you for that. That was the clarity i was after. Would it be right to assume if i set a buffer of bytes to be say 256 bits and that the total packet is large (say an image or video) then the process would be slow than if i had set the buffer to be 1024 bits long?  Also, vice-versa if the buffer was large but the packet was known to smaller?  (hope i explained that right)

Comment: Ideally, the buffer is at least the size of the data available. I recommend that you allocate a buffer of a certain size once and reuse that. Depending on how fast the connection is you can try sizes of 8KB or 64KB. Don't go much lower on fast connections because that will cause lots of read calls (which are kernel-mode transitions).